# gulp process terminated with code 0 when attempting to minify js files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, gulp

I am new to gulp and I'm getting an error as described in the subject.

> process terminated with code 0

Here is the directory structure created by npm

[image]

from my package.json file based on the Angular Tour of heroes tutorial and some other reference material on the net.

```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "myapp",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "typings": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.0",

    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash": "3.10.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  }
}
```

This is my gulp script

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');  
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

//take all angular related files
var npmSources = [
    'node_modules/@angular/**/bundles/*.umd.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js' 
];
var bowerSources = './wwwroot/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js';
var destPath = './wwwroot/lib/min';

// Delete the dist directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPath)
        .pipe(clean());
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
    return gulp.src([npmSources,"!" + bowerSources])
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath))
        .pipe(rename('libs.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath));
});


gulp.task('default', ['clean','minify-js']);
```

In the `npmSources` above I am trying to include all angular 2 related library files without having to type each line in using this -> `'node_modules/@angular/**/bundles/*.umd.js',`

The error message I get above leaves me no clue as to what is going wrong and where. Is there anything wrong in my gulp script? My intention is to copy to the destination path all the angular 2 related scripts minified into one file without having to type each library in. Later on I want to do the same for the css files.

This is what my `node_modules` folder looks like now after the package.json file gets saved in VS2015

[image]

As you can see there are many more folders there than what I have listed in my `package.json` file. I am assuming these to be required dependencies that dont need an entry in the gulp `var npmSources = [...]`

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and running the gulp task using its task runner. I am also using bower only because hammer.js is not available in the npm registry.

**EDIT** : Error code when running the gulp file.

```
[23:06:46] Using gulpfile C:\UI\Gulpfile.js
[23:06:46] Starting 'clean'...
[23:06:46] Starting 'minify-js'...
[23:06:46] 'minify-js' errored after 1.15 ms
[23:06:46] Error: Missing positive glob
    at Object.gs.create (C:\UI\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:73:39)
    at Gulp.src (C:\UI\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:33:23)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\UI\Gulpfile.js:38:17)
    at module.exports (C:\UI\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\UI\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\UI\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\UI\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\UI\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
[23:06:47] Finished 'clean' after 40 ms
Process terminated with code 1.
```

Comment: Have you tried paring down the gulpfile? e.g. what happens if `gulp.task('default',function(){console.log("no code 0 plz")});`, then keep your `default` as is and change `clean` and `minify-js` to just log messages

Comment: that gives this >>>> [22:47:20] Starting 'default'...
no code 0 plz
[22:47:20] Finished 'default' after 182 μs
Process terminated with code 0.

Comment: Good so we know gulp is working. Sounds like you haven't tried debugging this yet? Next I would try `gulp clean`, see if that works, then `gulp minify-js`, see if that works

Comment: With the clean and minify-js I get this >>>> `[22:48:48] Starting 'clean'...
[22:48:48] Starting 'minify-js'...
[22:49:02] Finished 'clean' after 15 s
[22:49:05] Finished 'minify-js' after 18 s
[22:49:05] Starting 'default'...
[22:49:05] Finished 'default' after 33 μs
Process terminated with code 0.`

Comment: clean seems to be working as the folder gets cleaned up

Comment: I removed the call to rename and uglify in the minify-js task above and just did a concat. and it seems to have worked

Comment: the problem seems to be coming when I call uglify. I will post the error next

Comment: Great that was my guess. Good to get some practice boiling the problem down too

Comment: seems like the error is caused by this line `[npmSources,"!" + bowerSources]` Converting `bowerSources` to an array and removing the pipe sign seems to work for now without errors. Will only know for sure when I write some angular app off what I have minified.

Answer (score 3):

As you figured out in the comments [edit: hmm... did I imagine that comment or did you delete it? [edit: aha it's back! haha]], the trouble is bringing the array `npmSources` into the `minify-js` task's `gulp.src` glob:

```
…
var npmSources = [
    'node_modules/@angular/**/bundles/*.umd.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js' 
];
var bowerSources = './wwwroot/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js';
var destPath = './wwwroot/lib/min';
…
// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
    return gulp.src([npmSources,"!" + bowerSources])
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath))
        .pipe(rename('libs.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath));
});
…
```

That's because with (*A*)

```
var myGlob = ['1','2'];
gulp.task('myTask', function() {
    gulp.src([myGlob]);
});
```

you're saying (*B*)

```
gulp.task('myTask', function() {
    gulp.src([['1','2']]);
});
```

when you need to say (*C*)

```
gulp.task('myTask', function() {
    gulp.src(['1','2']);
});
```

(I'm not actually sure that's *exactly* how the array is represented in *A* when it's swapped in for the variable. But even if, for example, it isn't read, the result is equivalent: in both *A* and *B*, gulp will throw the same "Error: Missing positive glob".)

Since in what you provided there's no reason to have a separate variable for the source files, you can save a couple bytes and provide it directly in the `gulp.src`. This is also a good place to start when learning gulp:

```
…
var destPath = './wwwroot/lib/min';
…
// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'node_modules/@angular/**/bundles/*.umd.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            '!./wwwroot/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath))
        .pipe(rename('libs.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath));
});
…
```

Note also that the `!./wwwroot/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js` doesn't seem to be necessary: you're removing it from the glob, but it wasn't matched to begin with. (That `gulp.src` line says, "Get `node_modules/@angular/**/bundles/*.umd.js`,
`node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js`, and `node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js`, and then exclude `./wwwroot/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js`.")